# Android ArrayList Overwriting Values Instead of Appending to List

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm attempting to update and `ArrayList` with new data - however when I attempt to do so - the previous data is overwritten and the new data is never appended to the list and I'm unsure why.

```
 if (keylist.contains(item) && !value.equals("start") && !value.equals("stop") && !value.equals("done")){

     final Integer number = keylist.indexOf(item);



            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    // GET PREVIOUS VALUES 
                    String previous_key = App.sharedPrefs.getString(LIVE_VIEW_KEY, null);
                    String previous_value = App.sharedPrefs.getString(LIVE_VIEW_VALUE, null);




                    // ADD NEW AND OLD VALUES TO LIST
                    mCallElements.clear();
                    mCallElements.add(new CallElement(previous_key, previous_value));
                    mCallElements.add(new CallElement(valuelist.get(number), value));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                     // SAVE NEW VALUES 
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = App.sharedPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString(LIVE_VIEW_KEY, valuelist.get(number));
                    editor.putString(LIVE_VIEW_VALUE, value);
                    editor.apply();



                }


            });


        }
```

P.S.

This is part of a `Twilio` chat implementation - full source can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/imNQdCJ0

Comment: you are clearing the arraylist in your code, mCallElements.clear(), thus they are getting overwritten rather than appended

Comment: If I remove that line they are never updated at all

Comment: @AndroidAndroidAndroid ,check the code in **runOnUiThread(new Runnable()** is execting /not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clearing the ArrayList with `.clear()` and then calling `.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This clears the last set of data, and then forces the Adapter to completely reload.

To make your life as a developer significantly easier, I would recommend using `DiffUtil`. This calculates the difference between two lists, and deals with the changes for you. A really good tutorial on how to implement this can be found on CodePath: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#diffing-larger-changes

The Android Documentation says:

> 'rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort'

But because of `DiffUtil` you don't have to care anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just want to add new data to the old data,you do not need to use `mCallElements.clear()`,if the notifydatachanged still doesn't update the data, I think you need to check if your ArrayList is the same object.I hope my answer will help you